# whatsapp web infinite list

Tags: html, infinite-scroll, whatsapp

I was copying outer html code  of infinite list of whatsapp web to  extract information of who has read and delivered my msg

but for last some time whatsapp has changed to limit upto 12  element only,

So is there any way to record all changes made in perticular infinite list

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this question is suitable for asking on Stack overflow. Also, I don't quite understand as to why someone would copy the HTML code of whatsapp web to extract information.

Comment: html code help me to see , which of my friend received and/or read message send by in group